# Why am I Getting Extra Characters Selecting Dropdown values in IE?

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer

I have a form that takes a user's address from a single address field, and uses Google Maps to load a map with a pin on their location. The form also has 2 select dropdowns, one for state and one for county. They get selected on an earlier, and just pre-selected here. As part of our code we check to see if the address supplied has different coordinates than just the county/State combination. Its a way to make sure they entered a unique address.

That code is failing in IE, b/c when the jQuery selects the selected text from those dropdowns, in IE the result includes a square character (ascii or unicode I assume) and a ton of space. In other browsers it is fine. So for example I will get this for an address in chrome or ff:

**"Phoenix, Arizona"**

But in IE I get:

**"          ﷯Phoenix,          ﷯Arizona"**

When that is passed into the Google geo-encode function it fails.

I can trim the spaces easily enough, but haven't been able to omit the odd char or even know why it only happens in IE.  The selects are dynamically populated, but there is nothing in the code that has extra space or a carriage return or tab that is visible.  Any advice is appreciated.

Here's the jQuery code. Note I have already added trim() to handle the spaces, and the ## is b/c this is a ColdFusion page:

```
var simpleAddress = $("##lookupStateID option:selected").text().trim() + ', ' +  $("##lookupCountyID option:selected").text().trim();
```

Here is what the select options look like (copied right from page source):

```
<option value="">
Please Choose
</option>
<option value="">
-----
</option>
<option value="1">Alabama</option>
<option value="2">Alaska</option>
<option selected="" value="3">Arizona</option>
....
</select>
```

This was reported by mu users in IE8, but I can reproduce it in in IE9 and 10 as well.

I can try to throw a fiddle together, but the code is 1400 lines of code so I'll need to extract several parts.  Putting up a full example isn't possible (I didn't write it!)

Comment: I'd check my file and page encoding and possibly server headers

Comment: When asking for help with IE, always specify version(s).

Comment: Could you provide a link or a fiddle?

Comment: And provide full code page sources with the relevant content highlighted or commented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the encoding. This looks like the page contains some non-printing characters or code is garbled. Save it as UTF-8/UNICODE to make sure it works.

UPDATE: Well, I see that the contents of the question have been extended. Before I get downvotes here, give me some time to find the sources. It still looks like some misassigned charset but I will need to confirm it.